# Зацикливается код на выполнение алгоритма

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Зацикливаться мой код, который переводит число из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную

```
   def decimal_binary(n: int, *, precision: int = 32) - list[int]:
    arr = [0] *  precision
    i = 0
    while n:
        arr[i] = n % 2
        n //= 2
        i += 1
    return arr[i - 1 :: -1]


decimal_binary(-256)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код действительно зацикливаться на отрицательных числах, т. к. в цикле `while n` число n не будет равно 0.

```
a = -1 // 2
print(a)
```

Оператор `//` -> `math.floor(a / b)`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

Для отрицательных чисел нужно писать свою обработку, потому как

```
-1//2 == -1
```

Но вопрос, что вы хотите получить? Какое представление для, скажем, -5? Если что-то типа `-101`, то проще всего запомнить знак, получить значение по модулю, его бинарное представление и вернуть знак на место. Если же что-то типа `11111111111111111111111111111011` — то это уже совсем другой вопрос...

Comment: Спасибо большое!